# How to correct way to use lib react-native-fbsdk-next in Expo react-native project

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a problem with the implementation of Facebook Sign-in.

I did:

```
npx expo install react-native-fbsdk-next
npx expo install expo-tracking-transparency
```

Added to ***app.json***:

```
"plugins": [
  [
    "react-native-fbsdk-next",
    {
      "appID": "21----0420----67",
      "clientToken": "71d9x",
      "displayName": "AppName",
      "advertiserIDCollectionEnabled": false,
      "autoLogAppEventsEnabled": false,
      "isAutoInitEnabled": true
    }
  ],
  [
    "expo-tracking-transparency"
  ]
]
```

***App.tsx:***

```
import { Settings } from "react-native-fbsdk-next";
useEffect(() => {
   Settings.initializeSDK();
}, []);
```

then:

```
eas build --profile development --platform android
```

Built without problems, I've installed it on my phone.

My error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'initializeSDK' of null
```

I tried other things, but not working, every property/method from fbsdk lib is null, why?

What I did do wrong?